# PosgreSQL 11 lost connection when i'm trying to create function with plpython3u [WIN10, pgAdmin4 3.5]

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, pgadmin-4, plpython, postgresql-11

I have always problem with PosgreSQL when new version appears. Again I'm trying to install extension plpython3u and with this hint [Error during: CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u; on PostgreSQL 9.6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39800075/error-during-create-extension-plpython3u-on-postgresql-9-6-0?rq=1) I have created extension.
I added directory to PATH and variable PYTHONHOME to environment. Now when i'm trying to create any simple function using plpython3u it crashed with information

```
Connection to the server has been lost.
```

Here is information from log pgAdmin's file:

```
2018-11-25 14:06:47,649: ERROR  werkzeug:   Error on request:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site- packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 270, in run_wsgi
execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 258, in execute
application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1997, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_login.py", line 792, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\tools\sqleditor\__init__.py", line 1512, in query_tool_status
conn.check_notifies(True)
   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\utils\driver\psycopg2\connection.py", line 1805, in check_notifies
self.conn.poll()
psycopg2.InterfaceError: connection already closed
```

I'm using FireFox for pgAdmin and Pyhton from EDB downloaded by StackBuildier
Does anyone know how to install this correctly  ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

after 10 hours of attempts i decided to install Python 3.6.7 it is not typical for me because EDB supports 3.6.5v and from previous experiences I assumed that the newer version certainly will not work.

I was wrong.

Again I copy Python36.dll (3.6.7v) into C:\Windows\System32 and now everything works properly.